# php | find in array by regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking the way to find one string in array of strings:

```
$array = ['string1'=>'custom', 'other string'=>'another', 'another'=>'again', 'custom'=>'pid|100', 'once again'=>'pid|'];
```

I need to find this element: **pid|100**;

String should containt: **pid|any positive integer number**

```
foreach($array as $value) { 
   // regular expression here
}
```

How can I found this value?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) for this :)

```
print_r(preg_grep('/^pid\|[0-9]+$/',$array));
```

Comment: Please take a look to my updated question. I have a bit another array.

Comment: It should act the same on associative arrays. If you only want the values you can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the return of preg_grep to make the results indexed.

Answer (score 1):

`in_array(preg_match('/^pid\|[0-9]+$/',$your_array),$your_array);`

### OR

`in_array(preg_grep('/^pid\|[0-9]+$/',$your_array),$your_array);`

if you need to check this particular element i.e. `pid|100` then just use `in_array('pid|100',$your_array)` there is no need to check using regular expression

hope this will help you in solve your problem

Comment: Thank you. Take a look to my updated question please. My input data has another structure.

Comment: if you need to check this particular element i.e. `pid|100` then just use `in_array('pid|100',$your_array)` there is no need to check using regular expression